# Supabase storage download return undefined

Tags: javascript, next.js, supabase

I'm trying to download a CSV from a supabase bucket and parse it. Currently, I'm getting "undefined" for the file. See code below:

```
const { file, error } = await supabase.storage.from('bulk-uploads').download('csv/218c1ad526a2e9d2cbacd9e49587c2e777a5bdd71675166133663.csv')

if (error) {
  throw error;
}

console.log("File Downloaded",file)
// parse the file
let filedata = Papa.parse(file).data
```

The file in console.log returns an undefined value. So I'm not sure if bucket permissions are wrong or something else is wrong.The file does exist on the bucket.

How can I get the file correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get the file if you use the `service_role` key? 

If you do, then it is about the RLS policies and you would also need to put your RLS policies relevant to this bucket in the question.

Comment: Thanks in the end it was my RLS policies